# Delay applicationDidEnterBackground screen capture

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to delay the screen capture made by iOS when app is entering background? The reason is that I'm sometimes showing a view when the user goes to home screen I want this view removed so it doesn't show when app is resumed. The view in question is a  `SSHUDView` (source code [here](https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSHUDView.m)) which I call `dismissAnimated:NO` in  `applicationWillResignActive`. This actually works in the simulator but not on real device (the `SSHUDView` still shows when resuming). Anyone have a clue how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the `SSHUDView` implementation it uses a `UIWindow` instance to display the content; it makes it's own UIWindow the key `UIWindow`:

```
[_hudWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Which is probably why it's so tricky to get rid of. You might try to do what `SSHUDView` does after it dismisses itself to return focus to the main window:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] makeKeyWindow];
```

When the hud view dismissed itself it sends `resignKeyWindow` to it's private `_hudWindow` object, you could possibly try to get a handle on that before you return focus to the main window, like so:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1] resignKeyWindow];
```

But it may cause unexpected problems because you're bypassing the `SSHUDView` API...

Comment: Giving you the bounty because your answer was the closest one. I have tried playing around myself with `makeKeyWindow` and `resignKeyWindow` to no avail unfortunately. Will give this a go one more time.

Comment: Wow, thanks Peter. Hope you get it sorted. make sure to let us know what worked.

Answer (score 15):

I think you should handle this in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

- **Prepare to have their picture taken.** When the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method returns, the system takes a picture of your app’s user interface and uses the resulting image for transition animations. If any views in your interface contain sensitive information, you should hide or modify those views before the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method returns.

Comment: Yeah this answer is better. Ignore mine.

Comment: You should call `-[SSUDView dismissAnimated:NO]` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly get the view controller displaying the SSHUDView to listen for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` from `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and hide it that way? Seems a little hacky, so it may not work. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, both simulator and real hardware. In `applicationDidEnterBackground:` you can create a temporary view controller with a black background and present it modally over the "topmost" view controller (in case there's already a view controller being presented modally). Simply remove it when the app comes back in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *veilController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *vc0 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc0.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc0 animated:NO completion:nil];

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [vc0 presentViewController:vc1 animated:NO completion:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.veilController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.veilController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIViewController *tvc = self.window.rootViewController;
    while (tvc) {
        if (tvc.presentedViewController) {
            tvc = tvc.presentedViewController;
        } else {
            [tvc presentViewController:self.veilController animated:NO completion:nil];
            tvc = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.veilController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    self.veilController = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Good answer, one note though: this will not work properly if rvc.presentedViewController is also presenting its own view controller (IE, if there's a view controller chain).  You should loop through the presentedViewController property until you hit nil.