# secure displayed data when going to background : applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, iphone

My application deals with sensitive data, and I want the data shown on the view to be completely hidden as soon as the user goes to background. I am trying to achieve this by putting a view on top all other views:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.someShieldView];
```

I also tried,

```
[self topViewController].view.hidden = YES;
```

I am doing this in AppDelegate's

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

as recommended  in [iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf) Page 51

> .....When the applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns, the
>   system takes a picture of your app’s user interface and uses the
>   resulting image for transition animations. If any views in your
>   interface contain sensitive information, you should hide or modify
>   those views before the applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns

But I still see my view and its data for few seconds. How can I ensure that my view is hidden behind a 'shield'?

I followed this post, but could not achieve what I wanted.

[Delay applicationDidEnterBackground screen capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161636/delay-applicationdidenterbackground-screen-capture)

What could I be doing wrong?

Note: one alternative is not to support multitasking, but I do want to support multi tasking.

Comment: What do you mean by "I still see my view and its data for few seconds"

Comment: I mean, The secure data in my view controller, that I want to hide, its visible for few seconds when I come back from background.

Answer (score 1):

After scratching my head over the exact problem for some time, I think I may have found whats going in.

The issue that you are facing happens only in simulator. On a physical device (I tested using iphone5s) if you hide your view in applicationDidEnterBackground, the temporary screen capture does not show the hidden view.

This is my entire code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // this is your secure content
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.window.hidden = YES; // this is where you will hide/mask your content
}
```